# Setting an xml from one of my class

Tags: android, xml, class

I want to create an xml file from my java class. How do I set the scaleType of my xml to fitXY programmatically? (I mean from another class, not in the xml file)

It should be something like this, but everything I try doesn't seem to work.

```
image.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//set like this

```
image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```